# remove a query string in htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have URL like these:

```
/one/two?page=1
/three/four/five?page=2
```

I need to remove "page=1" and redirect it to /one/two but only when "page=1" appears, not "page=2".

How can i do that?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/phanan/htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
```